# An old activity starts in tablet devices EVEN after I delete it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity

I just come into a very weird situation today which is when I use a tablet AVD device, my main activity starts with an old design which I want to change, but when I try changing anything in the UI nothing changes in runtime and android still loads that old activity design.
This happened when I created two activities; the main one for small screens and another with sw-600dp, then changed my mind that I want to change the design for tablets ONLY when they are in landscape orientation. So, I deleted sw-600dp activity and created an activity-land, but the tablet had stuck with the old one and does not change anymore.

I tried deleting the whole main activities to see what happens, however, the app still opens normally with that old activity. I also tried to search for that stuck main activity, maybe it is hidden, but didn't find anything. The strange thing that my code is referencing the activity normally EVEN after I deleted it entirely. Moreover, tried to right click on this reference and go to declaration but it didn't open anything.

Note: when I try another device that is not a tablet it acts as expected that there is not activity and app crashes as expected so there are no problems with these small screen devices.

Here is a screenshot of my activities and how my java code is still - weirdly - referencing an activity that does not exist!

[image: Screenshot of my activities and how my java code is still - weirdly - referencing an activity that does not exist!]

Comment: delete your build folder under app and rebuild it

Comment: It works!! Such simple approach and I wasted some hours on this. Thank you so much!